# Bot Framework Emulator failed to run on Windows

Tags: botframework

Downloaded BotFramework-Emulator-4.11.0-windows-setup.exe from the release page 'https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases'. After installation, the emulator cannot start on Windows 10 X64.

I tried it on my desktop, laptop and a VM in Azure. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you raised this issue on the emulator repo? There's not much detail here the community can help with.